# python: inserting a whole line into a list

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

with open('thefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f))
  import collections
  counter = collections.defaultdict(int)

  for row in data:
        counter[row[10]] += 1


with open('/pythonwork/thefile_subset11.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    sample_cutoff=500
    b[]
    for row in data:
        if counter[row[10]] >= sample_cutoff:
           writer.writerow(row)
```

in addition to writing the data to a file, i would like to insert it into a list b[]

can i just do `b.insert[row]` ?

Comment: The output file should be opened with 'wb' not 'w'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `b.append(row)`, but otherwise yes. And instead of `b[]` you want `b = []`. Another way to do it would be to make the list first, and then just write each element of the list to the file:

```
b = [row for row in data if counter[row[10]] >= sample_cutoff]
map(writer.writerow, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's list.insert(index, item) or list.append(item).

Also, `b[]` is a name error *and* syntax error. I suppose you mean `b = []`.

Comment: `()` is the syntax for the empty tuple. Lists are declared with `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `b = []` would support an `insert` method. The syntax is as follows.

```
b.insert(postiion_int, element)
```